# Adding new methods and properties dynamically during runtime

Tags: c#, xml, dynamic, expando

XML: `<class>  <method>a1</method>  <class>`

C#:

```
Class Demo 
    { 
      public string a1 { get; set;}  
      public void a1() 
      { 
        ----- 
      } 
    }
    class test 
    {  
     public static void main(string args[])
     { 
      Demo d = new Demo(); 
      d.a1();
     }
    }
```

The C# is compiled and it will be made as reference in another program.

If I add a new XML method, like `a2` after `a1`, can I get this method in run time using dynamic and expandos. If possible, please tell me how to do it.

Another thing, can that method be dynamically created at runtime as per XML file. For example, if `d.a1()` contains `<method>c1</method>` then it will show `d.c1()` from Intellisense.

Comment: The SO code formatting is easy to use, please make an effort to take advantage of it.

Comment: Don't you think you should explain the relationship between the XML and the code? Not every project does this.

Answer (score 0):

You better use dynamic libraries and reference them at runtime. See [Can I load a .NET assembly at runtime and instantiate a type knowing only the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465488/can-i-load-a-net-assembly-at-runtime-and-instantiate-a-type-knowing-only-the-na)