# programmatically add shell32.dll as reference

Tags: c#, asp.net

I refer to this

[Can I load a .NET assembly at runtime and instantiate a type knowing only the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465488/can-i-load-a-net-assembly-at-runtime-and-instantiate-a-type-knowing-only-the-na)

trying to add shell32.dll as reference, here is the code

```
    string assemblyName = "Interop.Shell32.dll";
    string assemblyPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(assemblyName);
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
    Type T = assembly.GetType("ShellClass");
    ShellClass instance = (ShellClass)Activator.CreateInstance(T);
    ShellClass sh = new ShellClass();
```

The above code has errors:

> The type or namespace name 'ShellClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Also have a trial

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("Interop.Shell32.dll");
Type type = assembly.GetType("ShellClass");
object ShellClass = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Error:

> The type or namespace name 'ShellClass' could not be found

I'm not really understand how to add reference programmatically. What is the problem of above code?

Answer (score 0):

You should include the namespace of the class in the GetType method:

```
assembly.GetType("Shell32.ShellClass");
```