# Load assembly from full type name

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I have library TestProject1. Namespace - TestProject1.
here i have class - Class1.
Can i load it from another project using full class name (TestProject1.Class1)? (dll is in another project's folder).
I want to see solution without going throw all "*.dll" files in folder.

Only dynamic load.

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465488/can-i-load-a-net-assembly-at-runtime-and-instantiate-a-type-knowing-only-the-na it includes dynamic loading and type activation/constructing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, since you have the reference of this another assembly in your project, you can create a Assembly object from a type and get some properties of this type, for sample:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Class1));

string fullName = asm.FullName;
```

If you need to load a assembly that is not referenced into your project, you can use the `Assembly.LoadFile` method, passing the path of dll, for sample:

```
var asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile("C:\\project.dll");

// Get the type to use.
Type class1 = asm.GetType("Class1");

// Get the method to call.
MethodInfo myMethod = class1.GetMethod("MethodA");

// Create an instance. 
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(class1);
```

And work with `asm` assembly object, you will not have a strongly typed code, but you can use `Reflection` to use the types from this assembly.

Remember to include the reflection namespace:

```
using System.Reflection;
```

Comment: I don't know about Class1 as class. I know only it's name. Class is situating in another project.

Comment: Class1 is in dll, which is in my main application folder

Comment: Look my edits, you can use the `Assembly.LoadFile()`.

Comment: Ehm, my own answer is to use

Assembly.LoadWithPatrialName("TestProject1.Class1");

Am i right?

Comment: i wanted to load without dll file name

Comment: If you do not have the assembly referenced into your project, you cannot do this. You have to pass the file and create a assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Ehm, my own answer is to use

```
Assembly.LoadWithPatrialName("TestProject1.Class1");
```

Am i right?

Comment: This is now obsolete