# Refer .NET assembly based on compiler switch

Tags: c#, .net

I need to add reference to another assembly in my c# project based on some compiler switch like `#if`directive. For example I want to add reference to logger DLL in my project only when I need it. Is this possible?

Comment: Smells like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain what problem you're trying to solve instead?

Comment: You could load the logging assembly dynamically, but it looks like more trouble than it's worth. Are you sure the extra referenced assembly is a problem to begin with?

Comment: This should help - http://stackoverflow.com/a/465509/744616

Comment: Yeah. I am developing a class library which I need to ship to customers. Already it contains reference may other external libraries. So if possible I just want to avoid it. Only when someone faces any problem then only I want to ship my class lib with logging capability by including logger DLL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, a referenced assembly that isn't used AT ALL, isn't a problem. You can even keep it as reference.

As long as your code doesn't trigger the assembly to be loaded, there is no need to have that file available.

I would suggest though to check whether you really need this, and if you can workaround this by creating interfaces and dynamically load the assembly (using `Assembly.LoadFrom`).