# passing generic list of reflected type to method in reflected type

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, reflection, runtime

I'm using a third party assembly at Runtime. The assembly exposes a single method accepting a generic list of a struct. The struct is defined within the third party assembly itself.

```
<thirdpartassembly>
public struct stStruct
{
 public string member1;
 public decimal member2;
}
public class businessType
{
public string processItems(List<stStruct> processItems)
{
 //process items, then return result
}
}
</thirdpartassembly>
```

Given an instance of [businessType] created at runtime using reflection, I am trying to pass a list of items [listofStructItems] to the [processItems] method.

How do I define/create [listofStructItems] ?

What I tried so far:

1. Passing a List containing stStruct items.
2. Creating a struct that has the same definition as stStruct (cstStruct) in my code, then passing a List to the processItems method. (cannot convert list of x to list of y).

Environment:

- third party assembly: .Net v.2
- my assembly: anything above v.2

Any thoughts ? I would also appreciate an explanation of why none of the options above did work.

Comment: Why are you using reflection? What is the issue with passing a `List<stStruct>` like it is expecting?

Comment: I am loading this assembly at Runtime, stStruct is defined within that assembly, and does not exist at design time. Creating a mirror of stStruct did not work (cannot convert list of stStruct to mirrorstStruct).

Comment: Why not include the assembly in your project and avoid the headache of trying to do the impossible?

Comment: This assembly cannot be deployed with the app (licensing limitations). It should be deployed to the app location after installation

Comment: why the -1? is there something missing in the question description ?

Comment: Looks like this is a duplicate of this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465488/can-i-load-a-net-assembly-at-runtime-and-instantiate-a-type-knowing-only-the-na](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465488/can-i-load-a-net-assembly-at-runtime-and-instantiate-a-type-knowing-only-the-na)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I tried so far:
>
> 1. Passing a List containing stStruct items.

Without code thats hard to say what was wrong.

> 2. Creating a struct that has the same definition as stStruct (cstStruct) in my code, then passing a List to the processItems method. (cannot convert list of x to list of y).

Well thats how typesafe languages work, its a different type.

The key to solve this problem is the `Type.MakeGenericType` method to create a generic type with a type parameter unknown at compile time. Keep in mind that the `Assembly.GetType()` method requires the type name inclusive the namespace. You can inline a few of these temp variables, i created them just to be a bit more clear about the general reflection process.

```
var businessTypeInstance = ...;
var processItemsMethod = businessTypeInstance.GetType().GetMethod("processItems");
var stStructType = businessTypeInstance.GetType().Assembly.GetType("stStruct");
var openListType = typeof(List<>);
var closedListType = openListType.MakeGenericType(stStructType);
var listOfStruct = Activator.CreateInstance(closedListType);
var result = processItemsMethod.Invoke(businessTypeInstance, new [] { listOfStruct });
```

---

Just for broaden the mind and even that i do not recommend this, you could get the `List<stStruct>` type from the parameter itself:

```
var closedListType = processItemsMethod.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;
```

Comment: Thank you ! 
Great Answer ! your explanation makes perfect sense.
I'll try to post the full code once I have everything working.