# How to correctly connect DLL while application running

Tags: c#, dll

I have a trouble with connecting DLL while running my application.

**What I have?**

1. I have **Interfaces.dll** where I defined interfaces which will be implemented by plugins. I've made new folder **Plugins** and copied dll to this folder.

   ```
   public interface ITable
   {
       string ToString(List<int> _intArray);
       List<int> ToHex(string _stringArray);
   }
   public interface IAbout
   {
       string Description { get; }
       string Name { get; }
       string Author { get; }
       string Date { get; }
       string Link { get; }
       bool isDefault { get; }
       void About();
   }
   ```
2. I have plugin **TableBasic.dll** which implements interfaces from **Interfaces.dll**. When I was making it, I've added **Interfaces.dll** to references from folder **Plugins**

   ```
   public class Table : ITable, IAbout
   {
       ...
   }
   ```
3. I have application where I have static class **Plugins** with static method **Load** which loading specified dll imlemenitng specified interface. I've added **Interfaces.dll** from folder **Plugins** to application's references.

   ```
   public static object Load(string path, Type seekingInterface)
   {
       Type DLL = Assembly
           .LoadFrom(path)
           .GetTypes()
           .First(t => seekingInterface.IsAssignableFrom(t) &&
           typeof(IAbout).IsAssignableFrom(t));
       return Activator.CreateInstance(DLL);
   }
   ```

**Error**

When I try to call load function as

```
Plugins.Load(@"D:\Repositories\Crystal\Plugins\TableBasic.dll", typeof(ITable));
```

I get exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no matching element'
```

But I don't know why, it looks like my application and my plugin use different **Interfaces.dll** and interfaces **ITable** and **IAbout** in my application and in plugin is different or... I do not know what to suggest.

Could you please to help me?

Why not a duplicate: I want to get type that implements specifyied interface, getting type by `assembly.GetType("MyType");` is not acceptable because I don't know name of type and I will not able to cast it to any interface if I didn't check type implements interface or not.

Comment: It does look correct. Maybe you could check the result of `GetInterfaces` on the class from your plugin DLL and see if there are any obvious differences to the types that you want them to match

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I load a .NET assembly at runtime and instantiate a type knowing only the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465488/can-i-load-a-net-assembly-at-runtime-and-instantiate-a-type-knowing-only-the-na)

Comment: tihs question has been asked many time in the past, take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465488/can-i-load-a-net-assembly-at-runtime-and-instantiate-a-type-knowing-only-the-na

Comment: The code: `Type DLL = Assembly
    .LoadFrom(path)
    .GetTypes()
    .First()
    .GetInterface("ITable");
Console.WriteLine(DLL.FullName);
Console.WriteLine(seekingInterface.FullName);`

gets me: 
`Interfaces.ITable
Interfaces.ITable`

Comment: And what is the output of `typeof(ITable).FullName` and `seekingInterface.FullName`?

Comment: @SimonPrice: I disagree that it is a duplicate. The OP generally seems to know how to dynamically load a type from a DLL. However, it is not working, he has a concrete problem with his approach. Are you able to find an answer to his concrete problem in the question or answer linked by you?

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth, they both return Interfaces.ITable and it's correct, I tried to get GUID of both interfaces and GUID's of both are identical.

Comment: In that case, try to reduce the problem: Try to create a complete, small example of the problem.

Comment: Do you mean to create new Interface, Plugin and Application projects?

Comment: Yes. Something that you can share with us

Comment: I made test solution and... it works good. I'm confused. Why it doesn't work in my not test project...

https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApdUzWbdZon2mSfakXpevw8K1z6U

Comment: Move part-by-part to your test solution until it does not work anymore...

Comment: Okay, I'm going to create new solution and will be move code from old. I will update this thread once it' completed.

Answer (score 0):

I've created new project and moved code from old project to new. And all works as I expected. I cannot explain why old project didn't work. 
I've compared files *.csproj of new and of old project and I didn't see any differents except ProjectGuid but it must be different in different projects.