# Load Library From different Folder C#

Tags: c#, dll

I am new to C#, and I have a project which I have a built as a class library to check for updates before the app starts.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9ibA.png]

For the program to run this dll file should be in the same directory where the main app is, I want to change the directory of this dll file to be in a sub folder.

I have tried to change `app.config` file, but it started to cause runtime errors.

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load a .NET assembly at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465488/).

Answer (score 0):

If you import Updater Project into your main project, MsBuild compiles both of them together. And you won't need to deal with such complexities.

Honestly, ı couldn't understand what you tried to do. But above approach would solve your issue.

Comment: Updater project is searching for updates, and if found, it will download update, then remove old version then start the newer version, so i cant do such if they are both in the same project then it wont be able to do so..