# Deploying DLLs to a Specific Location

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm in Visual Studio 2019, and I'd like to deploy all the DLLs in my project to a DLL folder and have the exe in another folder.  I don't see an option for that really though.
Can I do that?

Comment: There is no simple way to do that.  You could add an AssemblyResolve handler.

Comment: Do it as a post build step.

Comment: Consider a ClickOnce deployment.

Comment: Do what as a post build step... the AssemblyResolve handler?  Or just the copy of the DLLs to the other folder.  If I do that, won't the exe not be able to find them?

Comment: I think you'll have to do both.

Comment: Possibly the [assemblyBinding configuration element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/assemblybinding-element-for-runtime); specifically, the codeBase option.

Comment: Both will be necessary.  .Net expects assembly dependencies to be in the same folder or in the GAC.  You would have to (a) write a post-build step to move the DLLs to the desired folder, then (b) tell the app domain how to find those DLLs.

Comment: You can load any assembly at runtime using nothing but the path.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465488/can-i-load-a-net-assembly-at-runtime-and-instantiate-a-type-knowing-only-the-na

Answer (score 2):

As described in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies), assemblies are located using a particular algorithm. One part of that algorithm is to check the configuration file for [codeBase elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/codebase-element). These elements define a specific location (per assembly and version) to search for a particular assembly.

Alternatively, you can set the `privatePath` value for the [probing element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element). This would affect all DLLs for your application whereas the above could target specific DLLs.

So you would set up a post-build step to copy your DLLs (and/or EXE) to the destination folder, and update your app.config to have the appropriate `<codeBase>` or `<probing>` elements which point to that destination folder.