# Using assembly located in parent directory of executable file

Tags: c#, .net

In my simple console application I'm using dll assembly with useful functionality, and there are no issues when that files contains in the same directory. But how to reference to dll assembly, which is located in the parent directory of the executable file?

Comment: Have you added dll as reference or Invoking dll using  reflection ?

Comment: @user2932057 a reference to the assembly formed in visual studio

Comment: You can also load it at runtime if you know the file: https://stackoverflow.com/q/465488/1462295

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because the OS does not know where the dll is.
You can add the path of the dll to your environmental variables and it will work  or add the dll to a path that's already in your environmental variables.