# how to make 'B', 'C' codes are not to be loaded into memory to improve performance when 'A' is chosen among 'A', 'B', 'C' through if else?

Tags: c#, performance, if-statement, memory

Let's say we have car management software and codes are,

```
if (power== "gasoline")
{
   // many code
}
else if (power== "diesel")
{
   // many code
}
else if (power== "electric")
{
   // many code 
}
else if (power== "hybrid")
{
   // many code
}
```

As title of this question, I don't want the code of 'diesel', 'electric', 'hybrid' to be loaded into memory to improve performance when a user selects 'gasoline'.

Is there a excellent way for this case ?

Thank you !

Comment: Strangest one question. Which exact performance metric you want to improve?

Comment: @PWND, welcome any question. I can't understand what you mean exactly due to my poor english. I would just tell you the amount of codes which I don't want load into memory are 50,000 lines...That's why this question is important to me.

Comment: i seriously doubt that there's any way to do this that will save you any kind of performance.

Comment: @KayLee your question is wrong. If you want load less C# code - it doesn't improve your performance. Try to improve the approach of programming, I mean use async programming and so on.

Comment: @PWND, I'm a self-learning programmer without IT background. Thanks for your kind advice.

Comment: Put the `50k lines of code` chunks in different assemblies. Then load them on demand as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/465509/419761). However, I believe this will be costlier. Unless you have millions of lines :P

Comment: @l33t, many thanks for bringing good ideas to my small, trifling question. Because programming is not my working job, I hope I reach there in the future..:)