# dynamic lazy loading in blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

In a Blazor wasm project I would like to dynamically load a second project without knowing the project at compile time (.Net5).
Therefore the normal 'lazy loading' does not work for me.
Are there libraries for such purposes? Or an example solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I load a .NET assembly at runtime and instantiate a type knowing only the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465488/can-i-load-a-net-assembly-at-runtime-and-instantiate-a-type-knowing-only-the-na)

Comment: Hey, it seems like your "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, **software libraries**, and more" (emphasis mine), which is a close reason on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for this capability.
The static compile time referance in .net 6 is not great.

Have a look at oqtane they were doing some work in lazy loading at runtime back in .net 3.1, unfortunatly it seems that they went more into a nuget direction instead of just dll's
https://docs.oqtane.org/index.html
https://github.com/oqtane/oqtane.framework/discussions/1076

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31062499)

Answer (score 0):

A little late here but in NET 6 you can do it, I did a Manager where you can look at

https://github.com/elgransan/BlazorPluginComponents

Some example code

```
        var componentPackage = "RazorClassLibrary2";
        var component = "Component2";
        var stream = await Http.GetStreamAsync($"{MyNavigationManager.BaseUri}/{componentPackage}/{componentPackage}.dll");
        var assembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromStream(stream);
        componentType = assembly.GetType(componentPackage + "." + component);
        await DOMinterop.IncludeLink(componentPackage, $"/{componentPackage}/{componentPackage}.styles.css");
```

Where the files are in the server

Comment: can you debug theses assemblies ?